# PHP format date by locale (separators, order not text)

Tags: php, date, localization

For example 22.02.2014 vs 02.22.2014 or 2014.02.22.

strftime already expects a fixed format and just changes text.

Would it be possible (php 5.3 - large infrastructure, not yet updated) to use setlocale and format the date according to local specifications?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dt = new DateTime($datetime);
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
return $formatter->format($dt);
```

After digging around, this is the closest i found.